# JIRA User Permissions to AzureDevOps Migration

Tags: azure, devops, jira

I have a Excel of JIRA Users and there User Roles and Groups.

These JIRA Users have to be migrated to Azure Devops. and there Roles and Groups should also be maintained in Azure Devops.

Is there a way to programatically achieve this. or some import facility that will:
(1) against created Permission Groups, let me add Users bulk

[AzureDevOps Permission Groups which should recieve injected Users externally/non-manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DYID.png)